# Formula to calculate columns based on two values

Tags: excel, count, formula

I'm trying to count the amount of dates in Col M that have passed Col E

Col E - Due Date (Header) - All dates underneath as below
19/03/17

Col M - Completed Date (Header) - All dates underneath as below
23/03/17

The formula im trying to change is:

```
=COUNTIFS($M:$M,"<="&G6,$M:$M,">"&F6)
```

G6=The date of 24/03/17

F6=The date of 17/03/17

I'm trying to get it to count the days between these two ranges that are completed outside of the requested date if that makes sense.

Thanks to Ron. I've been using this formula to calculate how many are past that date but need to it have conditions applied:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(M:M>E:E))
```

Basically ... If Column M =< (G6=The date of 24/03/17) and If Column E > (F6=The date of 17/03/17) then SUMPRODUCT(N(M:M>E:E)) (Count all those dates that meet this criteria.)

Hope this makes sense.

I think it needs to be something like this:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(N((M:M<=Dashboard!G6)>(E:E<Dashboard!G6)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically ... If Column M =< (G6=The date of 24/03/17) and If Column E > (F6=The date of 17/03/17) then SUMPRODUCT(N(M:M>E:E)) (Count all those dates that meet this criteria.)

To replicate what you're looking for there, you can nest your N() function inside a couple of IF statements.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(M:M<=$G$6,IF(E:E>$F$6,N(M:M>E:E))))
```